# Select2 not follow the select when in bootstrap modal scroll

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I have a bootstrap modal dialog scrolling opened. And select2 inside. When I'm scroll down and open the select, the select box isn't follow the select parent.
Image

[before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9t1K.png)

[after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJw6A.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same question and I did not find any useful answers so I have made my own.
Probably is not the best, but it solved my problem.

I created an event triggered when scrolling inside the "modal" that attach the select2 items to its parents, which are then in its new positions.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('scroll', function (event) {
  $(this).find(".select2").each(function () {
    $(this).select2({ dropdownParent: $(this).parent() });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CrlsFR/oxfL8abt/

Comment: Great !n But if the dropdown is opened, the scroll is locked